# Задать цвет и ширину рамок в QTableView

Tags: qt, qss

Мне необходимо задать цвет и ширину рамок у `QTableView`.
Пытался сделать так:

```
QString strStyle = "QTableView::item{border: 5px solid #DCDCDC;}";
tableView->setStyleSheet(strStyle);
```

Однако ничего не изменилось.

Стоило поменять #DCDCDC на black/white/yellow (и любой из "известных" цветов), как всё заработало. Пытался так же использовать `rgb(220,220,220)`, однако бестолку.

Как мне задать кастомный цвет?

**UPD**

Выкладываю больше кода, где идёт объявление и инициализация таблицы

```
//! Хедер
class BoardsTable : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    // bla-bla-bla
private:
    void settingsGUI(); //! Здесь создаю GUI

    QGridLayout *gridMain;
    QToolBar *toolBar;
    QLabel *lblTitle;
    QAction *actShowRef;
    QTableView *tableView;
    // bla-bla-bla
};

//! Исходники
void BoardsTable::settingsGUI()
{
    gridMain = new QGridLayout(this);

    tableView = new QTableView(this);
    //! Устанавливаем цвет бэкграунда
    QPalette tempPalette = tableView->palette();
    tempPalette.setColor(QPalette::Base, EQUIP_BACKGROUND_COLOR);
    tableView->setPalette(tempPalette);
    tableView->setStyleSheet("QTableView::item{border: 5px solid #DCDCDC;}"); //! Опять-таки, с кастомным цветом не работает.
    tableView->setSelectionMode(QTableView::NoSelection); //! Нельзя множественно выделять
    tableView->setEditTriggers(QTableView::NoEditTriggers); //! Нельзя редактироваьт
    tableView->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu); //! Для ПКМ->меню

    gridMain->addWidget(tableView);
}
```

Comment: У меня работает (с). Серьезно. C `rgb(220,220,220)` тоже. Добавьте минимальный пример, воспроизводящий вашу проблему

Comment: @gil9red Выложил больше кода, если вы это имели ввиду. Если необходимы скрины, то так же могу выложить

Comment: Опять непонятно что не так могло пойти... Попробуйте очистить проект и запустить qmake. А у вас qt какой версии?

Comment: @gil9red В общем, ошибка заключалась в моей глупости. Я забыл, что задний фон такого же цвета (т.е. #DCDCDC). Поэтому рамки не отображались... 
Извините, что вам пришлось потратить время на столь глупый вопрос.

Comment: Хехе, у каждого бывают тупняки :)

Answer (score 1):

Устанавливаем произвольный цвет рамки для таблицы:

```
QString s = QString("border: 5px solid %1;").arg(QColor(255,8,8).name());
```

И/или устанавливаем произвольный цвет рамки для **ячеек** таблицы:

```
QString s = QString("::item {border: 5px solid %1;}").arg(QColor(8,8,255).name());

// Устнавливаем
ui->tableView->setStyleSheet(s);
```

Comment: В вашем примере цвет и толщина рамок меняется вокруг таблицы, но не внутри, т.е. айтемы как были со старыми рамками, так и остались. Кстати говоря, кастомный цвет для tableView поддерживается.
P.S. спасибо за второй пример с метода arg, это существенно упрощает многие моменты

Comment: @RecursiveDaun исправил